# Assemblies and Namespace

Tags: c#, .net

Does everything in a single namespace compile into its own assembly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you can have multiple namespaces within an assembly. In VS terms, you can think of an assembly as a project. Each project within a solution, gets compiled into it's own assembly. Within an assembly though, you can have multiple namespaces.

Answer (score 15):

No.

You can have several namespaces in an assembly, and you can use the same namespace in different assemblies.

Comment: E.g. System.dll and System.Core.dll both contain types in both the System and System.Collections.Generic namespaces (amongst many others).

Answer (score 2):

Assemblies and namespaces have nothing to do with each other except that there's a generally used convention that the full names of classes in an assembly will match the assembly name (in some way).

It's strictly a naming convention - as [Guffa said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668161/assemblies-and-namespace/668167#668167), assemblies can define classes for more than one namespace and the classes that exist in a namespace can come from more than one assembly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking if each namespace results in a seperate assembly, then no. One assembly can contain multiple namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

> Classes are organized in Namespaces just to keep a naming separation and organization. Think of namespaces as "folders" that contain one or more classes, and that might be defined in one or more assemblies (DLLs).

more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20056937/579381