# Internal class visible from another namespace in Unity project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, namespaces, internal, access-modifiers

I am organizing my unity project into namespaces, and want to hide the classes that are used only inside the namespaces.
I define the namespace MyProject.Accounts and place an internal class there:

```
namespace ProjectName.Accounts
{
    internal struct PictureData
    {
        internal int notSeenMember;
    }
}
```

Then i add the `using ProjectName.Accounts` to a file in `ProjectName.LoginScreen` namespace, and i am able to see the class through the Intellisence, and instanciate it, but not to use the `notSeenMember` member:

The MS says that : 
`Internal types or members are accessible only within files in the same assembly`.

Is being able to instanciate internal classes from other namespaces an expected behavior?

EDIT: you can also access the internal members

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Namespace or Assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530460/namespace-or-assembly)

Comment: @ZoharPeled that questions helps differenciate between the two, whereas i don't see Assemblies playing any role in my question. Can you elaborate on  how is it related?

Comment: They are related because `internal` is for the assembly, doesn't matter at all which namespaces are used in which assembly

Comment: Because `Internal` doesn't care about namespaces, only about assemblies. The fact is that you can access internal types or members from a different namespace within the same assembly. Your question suggests you have confused the two terms - *"Is being able to instanciate internal classes from other namespaces an expected behavior?"* **Yes**, as long as they both are in the same assembly.

Comment: Ah, i can see now, thank you. So there is no way to hide the class from others in the same Assembly?

Comment: Not by namespace, no. A private nested class would only be visible within the containing class though.

Comment: only by using `private` or `protected` (or `private protected`) - but I think that's more restricting that what you need.