# How to get type from different namespace than System in c#?

Tags: c#, reflection, types, namespaces

I would like to create types when being given **only strings** of their names. Here it's obvious:

```
Type t = System.Type.GetType("System.Double");
```

But when I try to get type from another namespace, like `System.Drawing`, the above method won't return the correct type. Working solution I've found:

```
Assembly foundAssembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SingleOrDefault(assembly => assembly.GetName().Name == "System.Drawing");
Type t = foundAssembly.GetType("System.Drawing.Color");
```

However, it looks pure and I guess doing it costs some time (`AppDomain.CurrentDomain` has 22 assemblies in my case, but multiplied by 10000, it's something). So can we get it faster? I'm not searching for a solution like `type = typeof(System.Drawing.Color);`, because possibly I'll have to translate `"System.Text.StringBuilder"` to its type and so on...

Comment: *"but multiplied by 10000, it's something"* Why would you load 10.000 assemblies? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer not **loading** that many assemblies, **searching** for that many times. In my project I'll have to do such parse from string to type really often. Possibly, the number of assemblies could grow. I don't understand downvoting my post btw

Comment: Quoting from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx), for the `typeName` parameter of `Type.GetType(string typeName)`: _The assembly-qualified name of the type to get. See AssemblyQualifiedName. If the type is in the currently executing assembly or in Mscorlib`.dll, it is sufficient to supply the type name qualified by its namespace._

Comment: @YogoWafel *"I don't understand downvoting my post btw"* Me neither, I think it's a valid question - maybe because the solution wasn't hard to google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make this work, you'll have to use the fully qualified type name (including the assembly). For `System.Drawing.Color` that would be (for .Net 4.0):

```
System.Drawing.Color, System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
```

```cs
Type t = Type.GetType("System.Drawing.Color, System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a");
```

to get the fully qualified name of an already loaded type, use

```
t.AssemblyQualifiedName
```

Comment: [Note that assemblies and namespaces are not the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530460/namespace-or-assembly). In the asker's example, it so happens that `System.Drawing` is both the assembly and  namespace of `Color`, but this may not always be the case.

Comment: @JoeSewell True - it would be best to save then fully qualified to begin with (however they are stored or processed).

Answer (score 2):

While the accepted solution properly answers the question, I would also recommend caching any of these conversions into a `<string, Type>` dictionary, where the `string` is the input you are parsing, and the `Type` is the result of the lookup. This should significantly improve your performance since reflection is slow.